# Google analytics _trackEvent not functioning

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have used _trackEvent for several links. But in google analytics it shows as 0 events and no tracking data are displayed.
Below is the code I used. Do I have to wait 24 hours to view the tracking data? or anything wrong with this?

```
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/example/" 
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Bags', 'Mainlinkbags']);"
target="_parent">
```

tracking code

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +      '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s)
();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is good practice to use "onmousedown" event instead of "onclick" because "onmousedown" is fired sooner, so GA script has more time to execute event tracking (it's only a few milliseconds difference, but can help). Try it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp

Comment: After 24 hours it works. but thanks for your suggestion. I'll try that also